# How do I properly hide preformatted text?

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

I know how to preformat text

```
This is preformatted

| . X . . |
| . X X X |
| . . X . |
```

And I know how to hide text

> This text is hidden.

But I cannot figure out how to nicely combine the two.

> | . X . . | 
>     | . X X X | 
>     | . . X . |

The best I can do is this, which doesn't look very nice.

> `| . X . . |` 
> `| . X X X |` 
> `| . . X . |`

Is there a nice trick for that?